# Extract values from xml file, bash scipt

Tags: linux, bash

gpsOutEnabled="FALSE"

smokeDetector="FALSE"

/>

siteName="Alzey002"

logicalName="FXU046"

>

sectorNumber="1"

latitude="4635826"

latHemisphere="NORTH"

longitude="377963"

geoDatum="DHDN-"

beamDirection="060"

height="3000"

sectorGroup="-1"

/>

sectorNumber="2"

latitude="4635826"

latHemisphere="NORTH"

longitude="377963"

geoDatum="DHDN-"

beamDirection="140"

height="3000"

sectorGroup="-1"

/>

sectorNumber="3"

latitude="4635826"

latHemisphere="NORTH"

longitude="377963"

geoDatum="DHDN-"

beamDirection="300"

height="3000"

sectorGroup="-1"

/>

radioBuildingBlock="RBB12_1A"

cpriLineRate="Ox4"

sectorNumber="1"

primaryPortId="BU1_A"

sectorSequenceNumber="1"

rruInstalled="NO"

/>

radioBuildingBlock="RBB12_1A"

cpriLineRate="Ox4"

sectorNumber="2"

primaryPortId="BU1_B"

sectorSequenceNumber="1"

rruInstalled="NO"

/>

radioBuildingBlock="RBB12_1A"

cpriLineRate="Ox4"

sectorNumber="3"

primaryPortId="BU1_C"

sectorSequenceNumber="1"

rruInstalled="NO"

/>

sectorNumber="1"

tmaType="NONE"

tmaType2="NONE"

tmaType3="NONE"

typeOfRet="RETU"

typeOfRet2="NONE"

typeOfRet3="NONE"

riuInstalled="NO"

riuInstalled2="NO"

currentLowSupervision_A="ON"

currentLowSupervision_B="ON"

currentLowSupervision_C="ON"

currentLowSupervision_D="ON"

/>

sectorNumber="2"

tmaType="NONE"

tmaType2="NONE"

tmaType3="NONE"

typeOfRet="RETU"

typeOfRet2="NONE"

typeOfRet3="NONE"

riuInstalled="NO"

riuInstalled2="NO"

currentLowSupervision_A="ON"

currentLowSupervision_B="ON"

currentLowSupervision_C="ON"

currentLowSupervision_D="ON"

/>

sectorNumber="3"

tmaType="NONE"

tmaType2="NONE"

tmaType3="NONE"

typeOfRet="RETU"

typeOfRet2="NONE"

typeOfRet3="NONE"

riuInstalled="NO"

riuInstalled2="NO"

currentLowSupervision_A="ON"

currentLowSupervision_B="ON"

currentLowSupervision_C="ON"

currentLowSupervision_D="ON"

/>

sectorNumber="1"

antennaType="2"

antennaType2="0"

antennaType3="0"

mechanicalTilt="0"

mechanicalTilt2="0"

mechanicalTilt3="0"

electricalTilt="30"

band="1"

fqBandHighEdgeBranchA="21250"

fqBandLowEdgeBranchA="21100"

fqBandHighEdgeBranchB="21250"

fqBandLowEdgeBranchB="21100"

fqBandHighEdgeBranchC=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchC=""

fqBandHighEdgeBranchD=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchD=""

fqBandHighEdgeBranchE=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchE=""

fqBandHighEdgeBranchF=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchF=""

dlFeederAttenuationBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederAttenuationBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

dlFeederDelayBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederDelayBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

dlFeederAttenuationBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederAttenuationBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

dlFeederDelayBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederDelayBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

sectorOutputPower="60"

beamDirection="060"

beamDirection2="000"

beamDirection3="000"

/>

sectorNumber="2"

antennaType="2"

antennaType2="0"

antennaType3="0"

mechanicalTilt="0"

mechanicalTilt2="0"

mechanicalTilt3="0"

electricalTilt="0"

band="1"

fqBandHighEdgeBranchA="21250"

fqBandLowEdgeBranchA="21100"

fqBandHighEdgeBranchB="21250"

fqBandLowEdgeBranchB="21100"

fqBandHighEdgeBranchC=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchC=""

fqBandHighEdgeBranchD=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchD=""

fqBandHighEdgeBranchE=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchE=""

fqBandHighEdgeBranchF=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchF=""

dlFeederAttenuationBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederAttenuationBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

dlFeederDelayBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederDelayBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

dlFeederAttenuationBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederAttenuationBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

dlFeederDelayBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederDelayBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

sectorOutputPower="60"

beamDirection="140"

beamDirection2="000"

beamDirection3="000"

/>

sectorNumber="3"

antennaType="2"

antennaType2="0"

antennaType3="0"

mechanicalTilt="0"

mechanicalTilt2="0"

mechanicalTilt3="0"

electricalTilt="60"

band="1"

fqBandHighEdgeBranchA="21250"

fqBandLowEdgeBranchA="21100"

fqBandHighEdgeBranchB="21250"

fqBandLowEdgeBranchB="21100"

fqBandHighEdgeBranchC=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchC=""

fqBandHighEdgeBranchD=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchD=""

fqBandHighEdgeBranchE=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchE=""

fqBandHighEdgeBranchF=""

fqBandLowEdgeBranchF=""

dlFeederAttenuationBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederAttenuationBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

dlFeederDelayBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederDelayBranchA="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

dlFeederAttenuationBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederAttenuationBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

dlFeederDelayBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

ulFeederDelayBranchB="0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1"

sectorOutputPower="60"

beamDirection="300"

beamDirection2="000"

beamDirection3="000"

/>

sectorNumber="1"

antennaSupervisionBranchA="10"

antennaSupervisionBranchB="10"

antennaSupervisionBranchC="0"

antennaSupervisionBranchD="0"

antennaSupervisionBranchE="0"

antennaSupervisionBranchF="0"

/>

sectorNumber="2"

antennaSupervisionBranchA="10"

antennaSupervisionBranchB="10"

antennaSupervisionBranchC="0"

antennaSupervisionBranchD="0"

antennaSupervisionBranchE="0"

antennaSupervisionBranchF="0"

/>

sectorNumber="3"

antennaSupervisionBranchA="10"

antennaSupervisionBranchB="10"

antennaSupervisionBranchC="0"

antennaSupervisionBranchD="0"

antennaSupervisionBranchE="0"

antennaSupervisionBranchF="0"

/>

carrierAllocationMode="Flexible"

>

sectorNumber="1"

>

cellNumber="1"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="461"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

cellNumber="2"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="465"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

cellNumber="3"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="468"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="1"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

sectorNumber="2"

>

cellNumber="1"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="462"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

cellNumber="2"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="466"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

cellNumber="3"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="469"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="1"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

sectorNumber="3"

>

cellNumber="1"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="463"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

cellNumber="2"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="467"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

cellNumber="3"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="460"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="1"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

Comment: Please manipulate XML with a tool that understands XML. What exactly is the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to do this with sed because you'd have to substitute a shell variable into sed code, leading to code injection problems (if the variable contains slashes, `&`, or some other character sed considers special in the context).

With awk you could do this:

```
awk -v runas="$RUN_AS" '/JOBNAME="NSVN1999"/ { sub(/RUN_AS="[^"]*"/, "RUN_AS=\"" runas "\"") } 1' filename.xml
```

Or to have the jobname as a variable as well,

```
awk -v runas="$RUN_AS" -v jobname="$JOBNAME" '$0 ~ "JOBNAME=\"" jobname "\"" { sub(/RUN_AS="[^"]*"/, "RUN_AS=\"" runas "\"") } 1' filename.xml
```

**But editing XML with tools geared towards plain text is not really a good idea** -- you don't expect XML-handling tools to break because someone inserts a newline in a benign place, for example. If you fix your XML (in the given example code, replace `JOBISN=` with `JOBISN=""` in the first `JOB` tag and close the `FOLDER` tag to make it valid), you can use a proper XML tool like `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//JOB[@JOBNAME="NSVN1999"]/@RUN_AS' -v "$RUN_AS" filename.xml
```

Where `//JOB[@JOBNAME="NSVN1999"]/@RUN_AS` is an XPath expression selecting the `RUN_AS` attribute of all `JOB` nodes whose `JOBNAME` attribute is `"NSVN1999"`.

Comment: runas="$RUN_AS" it will be the new value of "RUN_AS" of jobname "NSVN1999" bat when a execute i have in my xml out (RUN_AS="") ???

Comment: Does the shell variable `$RUN_AS` have the value of the new user when you run the awk line? Your sed attempt suggested as much. Anyway, `awk` must be called with `-v runas=newvalue` for the script to work, regardless of from where that value comes.

Comment: yes i get the new RUN_AS from (RUN_AS=`grep "RUN_AS00$num" $Path | cut -f2 -d:`)

but when i execute the remplace dont work !!!

Comment: Try `RUN_AS=$(grep "RUN_AS00$num" "$Path" | cut -f2 -d:)`. The thing you did tries to execute `RUN_AS00$num $Path` with an envvar `RUN_AS` set to `grep`.

Comment: num=1
        while  [ "$JOBNAME" != "EOF" ]
                do
                JOBNAME=`grep "JOBNAME00$num" $Path | cut -f2 -d:`
                #RUN_AS=`grep "RUN_AS00$num" $Path | cut -f2 -d:`
                RUN_AS=$(grep "RUN_AS00$num" "$Path" | cut -f2 -d:)
                TASKTYPE=`grep "TASKTYPE00$num" $Path |cut -f2 -d:`
                NODEID=`grep "NODEID00$num" $Path |cut -f2 -d:`
("\)/\1'$RUN_AS'\2/g' $TFILE > $out

awk -v runas="$RUN_AS" jobname="$JOBNAME" '/JOBNAME="jobname"/ { sub(/RUN_AS="[^"]*"/, "RUN_AS=\"" runas "\"") } 1' $TFILE > $out

it does not work :( helpppe

Comment: You're making the same mistake for all your shell variables, and if the pattern is a variable, you have to use `$0 ~ "JOBNAME=\"" jobname "\""` instead of `/JOBNAME="jobname"/` in the awk code.

Comment: awk -v runas="gggggggggg" jobname="NDEM1AP1" '{ sub(/RUN_AS="[^"]*"/,"JOBNAME=\"" jobname "\"" ,"RUN_AS=\"" runas "\"") } 1' $TFILE > $out
 like this ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601615/bash-variable-in-awk-command-variable-is-null?noredirect=1#comment45510309_28601615

nead help please